# asp.net set value to a label after page refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net

i need some help.

i have a user registration page with a label that say success on not and why not.

i need to refresh the all page after the user clicked the button 
AND show him the label value.
How can i do this ?

the code:

```
<asp:Button ID="CreateUserButton" runat="server" Text="Go" onclick= CreateUserButton_Click/>
<asp:Label ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

c#:

```
protected void CreateUserButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
try
                    {
                        ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
                        ErrorMessage.Text = "Registered successfully, ";
                        Response.Redirect("~/register.aspx", false);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                    }
```

Comment: Updated your label `<asp:Label ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server" Text="" Visible="False"></asp:Label>`

Answer (score 2):

Generate a click event **"OnClick"** for the button create user and write the code in that event

Please have a look at below Code and Update your code as mentioned below :

**ASPX Page**

```
<asp:Button ID="CreatUser" runat="server" Text="Go" OnClick="button_CreatUser" />
<asp:Label ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

**Code Behind (.CS) Page**

**Update:**

Update your code behind as mentioned below :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (null != Session["ErrorMessage"])
    {
        ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
        ErrorMessage.Text = Session["ErrorMessage"].ToString();
    }
}

protected void button_CreatUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Session["ErrorMessage"] = "Registered successfully, ";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, i didnt add the all code, i edit it, the code is working fine but how can u do refresh like response.redirect and also shoe the label after the refresh ?

Comment: postback will not refresh all page, i need for my reasons to refresh the all page after the button was fired.

Comment: ok. so for that you can use **response.redirect**. But it will reset the value of the **ErrorMessage**. so I will suggest to store the value (herer "Registered successfully, ") into session then **response.redirect** and in your page load you can check whether session has value or not. if it has then display that value to the label.

Comment: thats great. :) don't forget to upvote and mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the [click even](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)t and write the code you have in the event handler.

*HTML*

```
<asp:Button ID="CreatUser" runat="server" Text="Go"   OnClick="GreetingBtn_Click"  />
```

*Code behind*

```
protected void CreatUser_Click(Object sender,  EventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
        ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
        ErrorMessage.Text = "Registered successfully, ";
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
     }

}
```

> The Click event is raised when the Button control is clicked. This
>   event is commonly used when no command name is associated with the
>   Button control (for instance, with a Submit button), [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

use session variables/View state to store data and after refreshing display it on form.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.ASPX

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Refer the above link will give more clarity.